# c# MeasureItemEvent handler: e.ItemHeight not changing

Tags: c#, listbox, ownerdrawn

Is it me or can I only set the itemheight - e.ItemHeight - once for a listbox?

Although I handle the MeasureItemEvent on my ownerdrawn listbox and set the e.ItemHeight to the right value, only the first height that is set will be used.

Oops, I am new to this, sorry about that. This is the code (DrawItemHandler is of course in the actual program):

```
// Add eventhandler to draw and measure items
this.listBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(this.DrawItemHandler);
this.listBox1.MeasureItem += new MeasureItemEventHandler(this.MeasureItemHandler);

// The eventhandler itself
private void MeasureItemHandler(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.ItemHeight = Convert.ToInt32(mySettings.iCurrentSizeFactor * 10) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the code ?

Comment: Is the event fired more then once?

Comment: @Zenuka: yes, the event is fired each e.Index.

@Thomas: sure:

        /// <summary>
        /// Measureitem handler for the listBox
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void MeasureItemHandler(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
        {
            e.ItemHeight = Convert.ToInt32(mySettings.iCurrentSizeFactor * 10) + 1;
        }

Comment: @Erik - can you edit your question rather than posting the code as a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.ItemHeight` is initialized to `ListBox.ItemHeight` in the event firing. It does not save it's previously set value. You have to either modifiy `ListBox.ItemHeight` along, or keep track of your modifications in a variable.

---

EDIT: (following the comment)

The event is fired when a new item is added and only for that item.
It's fired also for all items when you call `ListBox.Refresh()`.

As I understand your code, you need to increase/decrease ItemHeight for all your items at once.

--> I think you have to call `ListBox.Refresh` when you update the TrackBar.

---

EDIT 2:

In practice, items height is changed when the ListBox receives [WM_MEASUREITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775925%28VS.85%29.aspx) which only happens when it's first created, or when an item is added. After the creation of the ListBox and all of its items at initialization, further changes within `listBox1_MeasureItem` for existing items due to a refresh are useless (seen with the help of Reflector).

I found a way to force a `WM_MEASUREITEM` to be sent to the ListBox without deleting and adding all items:

```
In place of ListBox.Refresh(), put:

ListBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.Normal;
ListBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
```

Comment: The idea is to take the standard height and multiply it with a sizeFactor. Default_Height * Size_Factor = Desired_Height. 

The sizefactor is controlled with a trackbar so the user can either increase or decrease the font size. 

Does that make more sense?

Comment: I do call ListboxRefresh(), the event is fired fine, the changed size - e.ItemHeight - does not get set. Expected behaviour is that once you handle the MeasureItem event I should be able to set the e.ItemHeight, no? (I am sure I am missing something, but what?)

Comment: That is it! Thanks, it works perfect now, thanks najmeddine (and all others that helped)!